# Try to override ttl for remote jwk in Spring Security with a jwtProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I want to override the default ttl of the cache for jwk

In documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/ad8c49acaed8d132b1d410fd8f7edaa4bb077bc7) I see that we can do it like follow:

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwtSetUri(jwkSetUri)
            .cache(cacheManager.getCache("jwks"))
            .build();
}
```

But I also need to provide a "JWTProcessor" to add some feature on JWT processing like follow

```
  @Bean
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWTProcessor<SecurityContext> jwtProcessor) {
    // Use Nimbus Decoder
    var jwtDecoder = new NimbusJwtDecoder(jwtProcessor);
    return jwtDecoder;
  }
```

But I don't understand how to combine both : I don't find builder with processor or setter with cache.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution not based on documentation

instead of doing it at the JWTDecoder construction level I did it at my custom  JWSKeySelector instanciation level

```
  protected static JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> fromUri(String uri) {
    try {
      var jwkSource =
      JWKSourceBuilder.create(new URL(uri)).cache(24000, 12000).build();
      return JWSAlgorithmFamilyJWSKeySelector.fromJWKSource(jwkSource);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
    }
```